# Fetching weekly, monthly, yearly data in one query

Tags: mysql, time

I have a page displaying users statistics and I'm wondering what the best way to get weekly, monthly, yearly and all time stats from a table is in one query?

At the moment I'm using separate queries to check for results within each date range but there has to be a better way. For example purposes, I'd like to count all rows there 'votes' = '1' in the past month, week, and year.

Comment: Please show your table structure, at least an approximate one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   SUM(IF(ts>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK,votes,0)) votes_weekly,
   SUM(IF(ts>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,votes,0)) votes_monthly,
   SUM(IF(ts>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR,votes,0)) votes_yearly
FROM table
WHERE ts>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 <something>` is equivalent to subtracting the days not moving the date to the start of the week/month/etc; so the data may not be accurate in all dates except when dealing with the first day of the week, month, etc. Depending on how sensitive the data is this answer may be disastrous.